# most frequently occured word in a database table column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table in MySql as follows :

```
  myTable
      col1 integer
      col2 integer
      col3 text
```

There are many more columns in the table, but for my question, these three matter.

What I want to do is that, I want to print the sum of column 1 and column 2. With this, I want to print the string from col3 which has maximum occurrence. If there are more strings with the same occurrence, I want to print which comes first alphabetically. How is that possible in MySql ? Is it even possible in single query? (This can be marked as a homework question. I am trying to figure out the solution but with my current knowledge base I am not able to do it. Some pointers on how it can be solved or some hints will prove helpful.

Comment: Can I have your marks when I have done your homework. Perhaps re-read the lecture notes and/or manual page for select

Comment: select sum(col1) , sum (col2) ,col3 from myTable group by col3;

Comment: The above query gives me the sum for various entries in col3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find most popular word occurrences in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761188/how-to-find-most-popular-word-occurrences-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for homework support, I'm not going to provide the query itself.

That said, you should look into [`GROUP BY` Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to calculate the number of occurrences for a word. In addition, look into [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) to learn how to sort your results. Adding the value of different columns is a simple [expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/expressions.html) which you can just write in the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) statement.