# How to find most popular word occurrences in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, denormalization

I have a table called `results` with 5 columns.

I'd like to use the `title` column to find rows that are say: `WHERE title like '%for sale%'` and then listing the most popular words in that column. One would be `for` and another would be `sale` but I want to see what other words correlate with this.

Sample data:

```
title
cheap cars for sale
house for sale
cats and dogs for sale
iphones and androids for sale
cheap phones for sale
house furniture for sale
```

Results (single words):

```
for    6
sale    6
cheap    2
and    2
house    2
furniture 1
cars    1
etc...
```

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL match() against() - order by relevance and column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259647/mysql-match-against-order-by-relevance-and-column) 

Not an exact duplicate but it answers your question

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated

Comment: Do you have a list of words?

Comment: @GordonLinoff a list of all possible words? or a large sample data set?

Comment: The question is pretty much clear and it also reminds me of recent vSauce  upload by Michael ["The Zipf Mystery"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCn8zs912OE).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extract words with some string manipulation.  Assuming you have a numbers table and that words are separated by single spaces:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(r.title, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) as word,
       count(*)
from results r join
     numbers n
     on n.n <= length(title) - length(replace(title, ' ', '')) + 1
group by word;
```

If you don't have a numbers table, you can construct one manually using a subquery:

```
from results r join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all . . .
     ) n
     . . .
```

The SQL Fiddle (courtesy of @GrzegorzAdamKowalski) is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0749/6).

Comment: Can you put this in a SQL fiddle?

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski . . . Thank you, thank you.  I had the comparison backwards.  Fixed and triple thanks for the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 7):

You can use ExtractValue in some interesting way. See SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b0a0/45

We need only one table:

```
CREATE TABLE text (`title` varchar(29));

INSERT INTO text (`title`)
VALUES
    ('cheap cars for sale'),
    ('house for sale'),
    ('cats and dogs for sale'),
    ('iphones and androids for sale'),
    ('cheap phones for sale'),
    ('house furniture for sale')
;
```

Now we construct series of selects which extract whole words from text converted to XML. Each select extracts N-th word from the text.

```
select words.word, count(*) as `count` from
(select ExtractValue(CONCAT('<w>', REPLACE(title, ' ', '</w><w>'), '</w>'), '//w[1]') as word from `text`
union all
select ExtractValue(CONCAT('<w>', REPLACE(title, ' ', '</w><w>'), '</w>'), '//w[2]') from `text`
union all
select ExtractValue(CONCAT('<w>', REPLACE(title, ' ', '</w><w>'), '</w>'), '//w[3]') from `text`
union all
select ExtractValue(CONCAT('<w>', REPLACE(title, ' ', '</w><w>'), '</w>'), '//w[4]') from `text`
union all
select ExtractValue(CONCAT('<w>', REPLACE(title, ' ', '</w><w>'), '</w>'), '//w[5]') from `text`) as words
where length(words.word) > 0
group by words.word
order by `count` desc, words.word asc
```

Answer (score 3):

This would give you single words (Just if I understand what your `single word` means.):

```
select concat(val,' ',cnt) as result from(
    select (substring_index(substring_index(t.title, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1)) val,count(*) as cnt
        from result t cross join(
         select a.n + b.n * 10 + 1 n
         from 
                (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
                        union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
                        union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a,
                (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
                        union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
                        union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) b
                order by n 
        ) n
    where n.n <= 1 + (length(t.title) - length(replace(t.title, ' ', '')))
    group by val
    order by cnt desc
) as x
```

Result should be looks like this :

```
Result
--------
for 6
sale 6
house 2
and 2
cheap 2
phones 1
iphones 1
dogs 1
furniture 1
cars 1
androids 1
cats 1
```

But if the `single word` you need like this :

```
result
-----------
for 6 sale 6 house 2 and 2 cheap 2 phones 1 iphones 1 dogs 1 furniture 1 cars 1 androids 1 cats 1
```

Just modify the query above to:

```
select group_concat(concat(val,' ',cnt) separator ' ') as result from( ...
```

Comment: @user it's count 100. So in this case, the subquery `n` would return 1-100. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row for details explanation.

Comment: What is the table name in this?

Comment: Works with MariaDB 10.1 too.

Answer (score 0):

Update

Idea taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/98491

This query works on my machine (MySQL 5.7), however Sqlfiddle reports an error.
The basic idea is that you should either create a table with numbers from 1 to maximum word occurence (like 4) in your field or as I did, use a UNION 1 .. 4 for simplicity.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  `id` int,
  `name` varchar(45)
);

INSERT INTO products
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'for sale'),
    (2, 'for me'),
    (3, 'for you'),
    (4, 'you and me')
;

SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count FROM
(
SELECT
  product.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(product.name, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1) name
FROM
  (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
  ) AS numbers
  INNER JOIN products product
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(product.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(product.name, ' ', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
  id, n
)
AS result
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Result will be

```
for | 3
you | 2
me  | 2
and | 1
sale| 1
```

Comment: You may mention that one would need a FULLTEXT index for this, supported for MyISAM and since 5.6 also InnoDB

Comment: Why is there no `substring` to split the string at each space?

Comment: @User you don't need split `match ... against` will give you an integer between zero and one which is higher for a better match.

Comment: The result is supposed to return single words and this doesn't. Check the original question.

Comment: @User Yes after you updated your question I now understand what you want to achive. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not well suited for this task, While possible there are limitations (the number of words for example)

a quick PHP script to do the same task may be easier to use long term (and likely quicker too)

```
<?php
$rows = [
    "cheap cars for sale",
    "house for sale",
    "cats and dogs for sale",
    "iphones and androids for sale",
    "cheap phones for sale",
    "house furniture for sale",
];

//rows here should be replaced by the SQL result
$wordTotals = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $words = explode(" ", $row);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (isset($wordTotals[$word])) {
            $wordTotals[$word]++; 
            continue;
        }

        $wordTotals[$word] = 1;
    }
}

arsort($wordTotals);

foreach($wordTotals as $word => $count) {
    echo $word . " " . $count . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
for 6
sale 6
and 2
cheap 2
house 2
phones 1
androids 1
furniture 1
cats 1
cars 1
dogs 1
iphones 1
```

Comment: Python is what I've been using to gather the data, but this could work. I don't use PHP that much, so do you mind changing the code to load the rows from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b0a0/32

Let's start with two tables - one for texts and one for numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE text (`title` varchar(29));

INSERT INTO text
    (`title`)
VALUES
    ('cheap cars for sale'),
    ('house for sale'),
    ('cats and dogs for sale'),
    ('iphones and androids for sale'),
    ('cheap phones for sale'),
    ('house furniture for sale')
;

CREATE TABLE iterator (`index` int);

INSERT INTO iterator
    (`index`)
VALUES
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),
    (16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30)
;
```

The second table, `iterator` must contains numbers from 1 to N where N higher or equal to the lenght of the longest string in `text`.

Then, run this query:

```
select
  words.word, count(*) as `count`
from 
(select
  substring(concat(' ', t.title, ' '), i.index+1, j.index-i.index) as word
from
  text as t, iterator as i, iterator as j
where
    substring(concat(' ', t.title), i.index, 1) = ' '
and substring(concat(t.title, ' '), j.index, 1) = ' '
and i.index < j.index
) AS words
where
    length(words.word) > 0
and words.word not like '% %'
group by words.word
order by `count` desc, words.word asc
```

There are two selects. Outer one simply groups and counts single words (words of length greater than 0 and without any spaces). Inner one extracts all strings starting from any space character and ending with any other space character, so strings aren't words (despite naming this subquery `words`) because they can contain other spaces than starting and ending one.

Results:

```
word    count
for     6
sale    6
and     2
cheap   2
house   2
androids    1
cars    1
cats    1
dogs    1
furniture   1
iphones     1
phones  1
```